# Code difference in Prolog

Tags: prolog

What exactly is making these two seemingly identical pieces of code behave differently. My guess is I'm not taking a fundamental Prolog concept into account.

```
% creates list from X to Y (integers) 

interval(X, X, [X]):- !.
interval(X, Y, [X|R]):- X < Y, X1 is X+1, interval(X1, Y, R).
```

The output from this is as desired, an interval with specific endpoints.

```
| ?- interval(2,5,L)
L = [2,3,4,5]
yes
```

But, this piece spits out a different result.

```
% creates list from X to Y (integers) 

interval(X, X, [X]):- !.
interval(X, Y, [X|R]):- X < Y, interval(X+1, Y, R).
```

Output:

```
| ?- interval(2,5,L)
no
```

Comment: Mind that `X+1` is **not evaluated**: for Prolog `X+1` is simply `X+1`. It is *not* an addition operator.

Comment: So it's an instantiation matter, right ?

Comment: what do mean with *instantiation error*? For Prolog `X+1` is syntactical sugar for `+(X,1)`. It thus is a *functor*. It is only if you use the `is/2` predictate, that it *evaluates* the expression. And thus will calculate what `X+1` is and unify it with `X1`.

Comment: Oh, didn't know about the 'syntactical sugar'. Guess I'll do my homework. Thanks

Comment: It's not an instantiation issue. It's an expression evaluation issue. `is/2` will evaluate the expression that is its second argument and attempt to unify that with the first argument. If you just pass an expression to a query, it goes as an expression/term and is not evaluated.